# CleanCSS warning when finds Import statements

Tags: npm, clean-css

I have the following file:

**styles.css**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap");

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  font: normal normal normal 16px Oxygen;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #1b1018;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
body > header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #69b684;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
body > main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 10px;
  max-width: 860px;
  background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border: 9px solid #ffffff53;
}
```

which I want to minify with: `CleanCSS`.

For that, I did the following:

```
$ npm install clean-css-cli -g
$ cleancss --output styles.min.css styles.css
```

But when executing the command, I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Skipping remote @import of "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" as resource is not allowed.
```

Is there any way to get rid that warning?

The output file is fine for me, though:

**styles.min.css**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap);body,html{height:100%}body{display:flex;flex-direction:column;min-height:100vh;justify-content:flex-start;overflow-x:hidden;padding:0;margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;font:normal normal normal 16px Oxygen;letter-spacing:0;color:#1b1018;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover}body>header{flex-shrink:0;color:#fff;background:#69b684;text-align:center;padding:20px}body>main{margin:0 auto;max-width:1150px;text-align:center;padding:50px 10px;max-width:860px;background:#fff 0 0 no-repeat padding-box;border:9px solid #ffffff53}
```

Thanks in advance!